# Is there a way to tell git fallback to normal diff if >50% characters are different in line?

Tags: git, highlight, git-diff

I like `--color-words=.` when individual characters are highlighted, but when lines are changed comletely everything is mixing up:

[image]

Is there a way to tell `git` to fallback to normal diff if there are many changes? For example more than `50%`